# Help with Trigonometric Functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

so while playing around with circles and triangles I found 2-3 limits to calculate the value of $ \pi $ using the *sin, cos and tan* functions, I am not posting the formula for obvious reasons.
My question is that is there another infinite series or another way to define the trig functions when the value of the angle is in **degrees** without converting it to radians, I know of the *taylor series* but it takes the value of x in radians and to convert the angle to radians you obviously need $ \pi $, So is there another way to convert the or maybe find the angles in radians without using $ \pi $ or maybe a series for the trig functions which uses degrees? Also I know as a rule of thumb  you always use radians in calculus can anyone explain to me why??
Sorry if i asked a really dumb question.
Regards,
Kinshuk

Comment: I'm sorry if I am completely oblivious to your obvious reasons for not posting the formulas but I would like to know what are these "obvious" reasons.

Comment: it's the risk of being copied, you know in the digital age nothing is safe sorry if u think i'm being too paranoid but i learned it the hard way :)

Comment: So you came to us for help, but insulted us by insinuating we're plageurists?  I have a great answer to your question, but I won't post it for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The summation for $\sin$ with degrees requires $\pi$:
$$\sin(x^\circ)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{180^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}$$
Notice how all I did was substitute $\frac{\pi x}{180}$ into the power series for sin with radians since that's the conversion from degrees to radians. There's just no way to avoid $\pi$ in the series if you're going with a Taylor series and degrees.

The reason we use radians in calculus all the time because it's easier. For example, these are the derivatives for $\sin$ and $\cos$ in radians:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)$$
Now, here it is for degrees:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x^\circ)=\frac{\pi}{180}\cos(x^\circ)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^\circ)=-\frac{\pi}{180}\sin(x^\circ)$$
That's why we use radians instead of degrees or gradians: It gets rid of the factor in front of the derivative and makes everything a lot simpler, especially in more complicated calculus.

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ in radians
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+...=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}$$
To transform the angle $x$ into degrees, use $y=x\cdot180/\pi$. So for the angle in degrees:
$$\sin(y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i (180 y/\pi)^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you  kinda lost the original question

Comment: @Andrei: It should be πy/180, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry. You are right

Answer (score 0):

Well...you could avoid the $\pi$ in the previous answers by substituting for it one of the many infinite series formulas for $\pi$. That'd get rid of the $\pi$, but wouldn't be much practical use, which may be why you're not seeing it all over the internet. :)

I actually *do* occasionally want to know the sine of an angle in degrees. Fortunately, 60 degrees is close enough to 1 radian that the formula
$$
\sin^{\circ} (x) = \frac{x}{60}
$$
for $x$ an angle in degrees, no more than about $\pm 10$ --- based on $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$
 ---  works pretty well. Rule of thumb navigators (and lifeboat navigators) have used this idea for many years.